# How to send input data in the action of the form in php?

Tags: php, html, cakephp-2.0

This is my form page.

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->create('Searchs', array('type' => 'get', 'action' => 'view', 'class' => 'navbar-search'));?>

   <input name="q" type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search...">

<?php echo $this->Form->end();?>
```

Below is my action function in the controller

```
public function view($exam_id = 0, $q = null) {

    $res = array();
    $this->loadModel('Question');        
    $params = array('conditions' => array(
                                       'MATCH(Question.body) AGAINST("'. $q .'")',
                                       'Question.exam_id' => $exam_id,
                                       ));

    if($exam_id && $q){
        $res = $this->Question->find('all', $params);
    }
    $this->set('res',$res);
}
```

Whatever is typed in the input "q" i need to pass it in the url so that, the view action is called. How do i do this?

Comment: It will automatically control by get method. You don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @Rikesh No its not working. I have tried it.

Comment: I can't see submit button in your code.

Comment: @user2331441 u need to use AJAX for this ..on keypress blah blah blah

Comment: @Rikesh yes i am doing it onkeypress of enter button.

Comment: Are you planning to show the results without a page load? Because for that you need some ajax functionality. Otherwise the form is being sent where "action" points and form can be handled there.

Comment: @JaakkoKaski No, i am loading the page again. No ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, what i was looking for. This statement what was needed in my view.

```
`$this->request->data['q'];`
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply looking for

```
$q = $_REQUEST['q'];
```

or

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
```

since you know it's a get parameter.

Comment: No, When i am sending input data, that data has to be passed as a parameter to my action function of the controller. I want something like this (example.com/searchs/view/input_data)